# How do I control input to my method?

Tags: java, validation, parameters

I have a search method to retrieve records from database and I want to restrict the user to only search by name. I have a `SearchBy` enum with list of search parameters and for particular `SearchBy` methods the user can only search by certain values.

```
public List<Book> getBooks(SearchBy identifierName,List<String> identifierList) throws UnsupportedOperationException{

    List<Book> resultList = new ArrayList<Book>();

    if (identifierName.equals(SearchBy.TITLE)) {
        //returns list of BookObjects
    } else if (identifierName.equals(SearchBy.AUTHOR)) {
        //returns list of BookObjects
    } else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Books can be retrieved only using book titles or author names");
    }
}
```

Instead of validating and throwing an exception, how can we make it clear that only the values `TITLE` and `AUTHOR` are allowed as input for identifier names?

Comment: I have some vague idea of what you mean but your question is not very clear. Please do not use words like "functions" without defining them. In Java we use the word "methods", unless you mean something other than methods? You say you have a searchby enum, but you don't show this, or explain how it limits things. It's all very unclear.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to validate the name that is passed into the search method?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to "control" the user only searching by name? Please share your implementation.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. I'm out of close votes.

Comment: Please check the question and the related code.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used it but this framework makes some sense for your requirement:

[**Java Argument Validation**](http://java-arg-val.sourceforge.net/)

> An easy way for checking the preconditions of (public) methods and
>   constructors. All arguments can be checked, before an
>   IllegalArgumentException is thrown. Creating consistent messages for
>   inconveniences in argument values.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you mean, but if you are trying to validate input to a method it's common to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` for bad inputs and the client code can then handle this as they desire.

You would typically do something like this to validate input to a method:

```
public void method(String name) throws InvalidArgumentException {

    if (isInvalid(name)) { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The name is invalid");
    }
    else {
        // rest of method ...
    }
}
```

It's up to you to decide how to validate the actual name depending on the rules you want to enforce. You can then give a suitable message  in the exception to explain why it might not have been valid. Perhaps a regex could be used for the validation code, but without knowing the validation requirements it's impossible to suggest one here.